# Issue while substring a line while reading a line from a file

Tags: shell-script

`DMGR_PATH.out` file Contains

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/70/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config CELLNAME
/IBM/websphere/was7.0/profiles/Dmgr01/config CELLNAME
```

Now I have tried to read this file and substring the line like below..

```
while IFS= read -r PATH; do

        if [[ $PATH == /IBM/* ]] && [[ "$1" == "XX" ]]; then
        SEARCH_DIR=$PATH
        else if [[ $PATH == /opt/* ]] && [[ "$1" == "YY" ]]; then
        SEARCH_DIR=$PATH
                fi
        fi
done<DMGR_PATH.out

echo "$SEARCH_DIR" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

But it showing this error.

```
a: line 9: cut: No such file or directory
```

Can some one please help on this?

Comment: Of all the possible variable names to choose from, why on earth would you pick PATH?

Comment: PATH is, in this case, as bad choice as user variable, however, I see no reason to downvote.

Comment: can you please explain what exactly you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `PATH` in your script, as a loop variable. This happens to also be the environment variable that the shell uses to look up external utilities/commands.

That's why it can't find the external utility `cut` after the loop.

Please use another variable name.

In general, I personally tend to avoid using uppercase variable names in shell scripts, unless I specifically want to use the values of the variables exported into the script from the shell itself, such as `HOME`, `PWD` and `PATH`.

Comment: :: Its working now after changing the variable names. Thanks a lot:):)